# In Rx, how do I properly loop a network call?

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

I have a network call that returns a list of items.  I want to keep repeating that network call until the number of items is different than the initial count, or 5 seconds have passed.  I tried this:

```
timer = 0;
while (initialCount== afterCount && timer != 5) {
  try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    timer++;
    Observable<List<Item>> itemObservable = getItemsFromNetwork();
    itemObservable.subscribe(new Observer<List<Item>>() {
                                 @Override public void onCompleted()   
                                 { Log.d("DEBUG", "onCompleted"); }

                                 @Override public void onError(
                                 Throwable e) { Log.d("DEBUG", "e"; }

                                 @Override public void onNext(
                                 List<Item> items) {
                                   afterCount=items.size();
                                   Log.d("DEBUG", "onNext, " +  
                                   afterCount + " items.  "  
                                   + timer + " secs passed");
                                 }
                               });
} catch (Exception e) { }
```

I've confirmed that initialCount is always 5, so I'm confused why this gets printed:

```
onNext, 5 items.  1 seconds passed
onCompleted
onNext, 5 items.  2 seconds passed
onCompleted
onNext, 4 items.  3 seconds passed
onCompleted
onNext, 4 items.  4 seconds passed
onCompleted
```

The last onNext should not have been hit because the loop should have broke out.  What is the proper way to implement it?  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want (checked that it compiles, but not that it works):

```
        var x = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
            .Take(5)
            .SelectMany(_ => getItemsFromNetwork())
            .DistinctUntilChanged(l1 => l1.Count)
            .Take(2);
```

I think this does most of what you want to do:

- It polls every second.
- It only polls 5 times
- It only passes on the ones where the # of elements have changed.
- And it will pass on the first one (initialCount) and then one after that that has changed.

How you initialize the initialCount above wasn't quite specified, so this may not do exactly the right thing. Also, I'm still learning exactly how Take works when it gets to the end: I'm 80% sure that getItemsFromNetwork will only be called twice if the first two calls return a different number.

If you are in the situation where initialCount is coming from elsewhere in your program, and not from a call just before your call fragmet to getItemsFromNetowkr, then perhaps you can replace the DistinctUntilChagned line with a simple Where?

```
        var x = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
            .Take(5)
            .SelectMany(_ => getItemsFromNetwork())
            .Where(l1 => l1.Count != intialCount)
            .Take(1);
```

Finally, in both cases, you'd subscribe to x with your debugging statements above and it should work.

Comment: RxJava note: You should run the timer on Schedulers.io() because flatMap would do the network call on the Schedulers.computation().

Comment: If `.Timer(...)` in RxJava is the same as in .NET then it only fires once. You may need to use `.Interval(...)`.